# how to argsort with an array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use argsort on an array of float arrays, but faced some problem.
Here is what I try to do:

```
import numpy as np 
z = np.array([np.array([30.9,29.0,5.87],dtype=float),np.array([20.3,1.3,8.8,4.4],dtype=float)])  # actually z is transferred from a tree using root2array whose corrseponding branches is a vector<vector<float>>  
Index_list = np.argsort(z)
```

Then I　received:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)
```

So what should I do to modify z or change the way of argsort to make it work?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `z` is not a regular-typed Numpy array. It's an `object` type which means that it contains uneven sub arrays. You can fill the missing items with a proper type (`np.inf`, `np.nan`, etc.) and perform the `argsort`.

Comment: Which `z` element is largest?  why?  One has 4 elements, the other 3.  It can't do any sort of comparison, can it?

Comment: I see It is miscomparing, maybe I should check the structure of the input. Thanks.